# Angular 2 testing with global providers

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-cli

I am testing a lot of components in an angular cli project, and I'm using `RouterTestingModule` in some of them to stub the router. I'd like to just add `RouterTestingModule` to all tests so I don't have to selectively add it.

I added it to the test setup in `test.js` like below, but it does not seem to be included in the test modules for the components. Is this the correct way to include "global" providers?

```
Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/router/testing'),
])
    // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
    .then(([testing, testingBrowser, testingRouter]) => {
        testing.getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
            testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
            testingRouter.RouterTestingModule,
        );
    })
    // Then we find all the tests.
    .then(() => require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
    // And load the modules.
    .then(context => context.keys().map(context))
    // Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
    .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```

The docs say this about `initTestEnvironment`:

> This may only be called once, to set up the common providers for the
>   current test suite on the current platform.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but solution is to pass an array of providers to platformBrowserDynamicTesting() function.

```js
Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/router/testing'),
])
    // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
    .then(([testing, testingBrowser, testingRouter]) => {
        testing.getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
            testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting([..<providers here>..])
        );
    })
    // Then we find all the tests.
    .then(() => require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
    // And load the modules.
    .then(context => context.keys().map(context))
    // Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
    .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```